# django query - how to get latest row during distinct

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

this is my db RATING table where i want the last row of duplicate entries:

[image]

i did this:

```
bewertung = Rating.objects.filter(von_location=1).distinct('von_location')
```

but i am getting the first row where `bewertung`=4. i want the last row with this property. how can i get `bewertung`=3, the last row of `von_location` column? what is the best way for this to get?

Comment: Read the documentation, it's very good for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you want the record with the largest `id` (among the records with the right value for `von_location`). That's the first record retrieved when you sort them in descending order by the `id` column:

```
Rating.objects.filter(von_location=1).order_by('-id')[0]
```

Comment: thanks, but it is giving me now error: ``list index out of range`` if i do so. what does it mean?

Comment: It means that the query returned no results: there are no entries in the `Rating` table with `von_location=1`.